# this is scenario to automate

Tags: selenium

a) Go to http://money.rediff.com/gainers/bse

b) There will be a list of company names and their current prices listed in the grid

c) Find any company say 'SPIC.' and then read the current share value from 'Current Price (Rs)' column

d) Look at the top of the page, you will see a search field.

c) Enter the same company name and search for the same company-'SPIC'

d) Verify page with 'SPIC' details is loaded

e) In that page verify the price is same as the once which you had read earlier from the grid

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: This seems like a test-case, what is the question?

Comment: What is your expectation above? Please update. But I think you want to compare price, if yes, then "QA4it" gave the solution for your query.

Comment: Hello buddy, what is this about? Are you trying to tell us something or is there a problem for which you want help?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? What works, and what doesn't? Are there any particular steps you need help with?

Comment: @anshu Just do it :)

Answer (score 2):

@anshu  Use `.getText` method and store the value in a string (Both step C and E) and compare the both the Strings, Ex: `.equals`. (Also you can use if-else condition).